JCenter shut down completely in August and it was the only repo that had a package one of our apps uses
I have an older app that I maintain and it uses a tool "com.baoyz.swipemenulistview".  JCenter was the only repository that had this package, it seems.  There is a github page for it (https://github.com/baoyongzhang/SwipeMenuListView), but no new activity for several years.  I have downloaded the files from it.  How can I package the necessary files from it and import it using maven manually?

Create a library module for your project. Copy the files from library from the GitHub repo into that module. Make any necessary changes to the code or its Gradle script to take into account 9 years of SDK and build process drift. Then, switch your app to depends on your library module instead of the no-longer-available public artifact.

Quite often https://www.jitpack.io/ works as it will build it from the github repo
